# Wrong setter is called when row is selected

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I got the following problem using Primefaces 5.2 and JSF 2.1

I got a p:dataTable, and when the user selects a row, the selected object's  data should be shown below the table. One requirement is that there should be a checkbox below the table, which should be editable. If the user toggles the checkbox and selects a different entry in the table, the checkbox' new value should be saved. (see the code below)

But I observed the following behaviour. When I select object1, check its checkbox and then select object2, object2's setter will be called, not object1's. Thus object2.someValue will be changed, while object1.someValue won't be. any idea?

```
<p:dataTable var="myVar" selectionMode="single"
            id="myTable" selection="#{form.myValue}"
             rowKey="#{myVar.id}"
            value="#{form.myTableData}">

<!-- columns here -->
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" process="my_booleancheckbox" update="wrapper">
<p:dataTable>

<h:panelGroup id="wrapper">
    <p:booleanCheckbox value="#{form.myValue.someValue}" id="my_booleancheckbox"/>
    <!--other stuff here -->
</h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it is supposed to work, the `rowSelect` event is fired after the property `selection` of your `p:dataTable` is updated

move your ajax action to the `p:booleanCheckbox`

```
<p:dataTable var="myVar" selectionMode="single"
        id="myTable" selection="#{form.myValue}"
         rowKey="#{myVar.id}"
        value="#{form.myTableData}">

<!-- columns here -->    
<p:dataTable>

<h:panelGroup id="wrapper">
    <p:booleanCheckbox value="#{form.myValue.someValue}" id="my_booleancheckbox">
        <p:ajax process="my_booleancheckbox" update="wrapper">
    </p:booleanCheckbox>
    <!--other stuff here -->
</h:panelGroup>
```